# How can I pass the checked checkbox values to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Is there a way for this? What I want to happen is the hyperlinks from the left side will have sum totals, and so on and on the final page/tab, the summation of all the hyperlinks will be shown there. Here's a jsFiddle to better understand my point https://jsfiddle.net/nerdfighter/121myofn/1/

Here's the initial JavaScript code I wrote in adding the checked chekcboxes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
    total = document.getElementById('payment-total');

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
      var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
      total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + add
      var new_total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input').value);
      console.log(new_total);
      document.getElementById('input').value = new_total + add
    }
  }
}

  </script>
```

This is just a small project and I don't I won't be using server-side.

Comment: There is a very fundamental HTML rule being violated in OP code. **IDs are unique.** Repeating: **IDs MUST BE UNIQUE**. You have over 40 checkboxes with **`id = "outside"`**. As for the JavaScript, it references elements that do not exist in OP HTML. If OP code did accurately reference the mystery node:`total` and/or `input` and properly collect the inputs into a NodeList, HTMLCollection, or array...the OP code appears to do very little. Even if the OP code was logical and functioning it would only process **ONE** value . JavaScript always assumes there's only `#ID` and it will stop at there.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `id="payment-total"` nor `id="input"` elements in your jsFiddle. So it won't work.

The algorithm is looking correct. But I recommend to pay more attention to strict code formatting - that helps to avoid mistakes.

I've added the following lines and jsFiddle began to work:

```
<span id="payment-total">0</span>
<input id="input" value="0">
```

---

**Update by comments:**

```
// TODO: Start using addEventListener() instead
window.onload = function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
        total = document.getElementById('payment-total');

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].onchange = function() {
            var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);

            // TODO: Consider state variables instead of parsing innerHTML
            // TODO: Never miss semicolons. It works, but causes hard debug sometimes
            total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + add  
            var new_total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input').value);
            console.log(new_total);
            document.getElementById('input').value = new_total + add

            // Per tab total calculation
            var tabTotalEl = document.getElementById(this.dataset.tabTotalId);
            tabTotalEl.innerHTML = parseFloat(tabTotalEl.innerHTML) + add;
        }
    }
}
```

Add sum elements like this

```
<span id="tab-vegetables-total">0</span>
```

Add `data-tab-id="tab-vegetables-total"` attributes to the checkboxes.

Comment: So sorry, I forgot to add it. I already know how to work around that part. But what I want to to know is how is it gonna play out if the hyperlinks have their own sum and it'll be shown to the final/total tab.

Comment: @ckdirecto it is hard to understand your particular task. Which hyperlinks? Which way those hyperlinks should include the sum? What is the "final/total tab"? I do not see any tabs in the code samples.

Comment: The hyperlinks that you see at the top will then be tabs, haven't made the css code yet. Inside the tabs ie fruits (when a user ticks/unticks checkboxes, the sum of the page will simultaneously change). Like I said, what I want to happen is the sum from the tabs caused by the user's choice by checking/unchecking boxes, I want them all added in the last tab to see the summation of all the checked checkboxes. I'm thinking of passing the total sum to another html pages (hence the hyperlink) as a way and I don't seem to get around it yet thus this post.

Comment: @ckdirecto Added the solution to my answer either.